# return items that all records related to that items have specific conditions

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

please consider this scenario:

I have a table like this:

```
ID              City            Status
--------------------------------------
 1               1                1
 2               1                1
 3               1                1
 4               2                1
 5               2                0
 6               3                1
 7               3                1
 8               3                1
 9               3                1
 10              4                3
 11              4                1
 12              4                0
```

I want to return Citis that all records that related to that city have `Status=1` and if one of that records has `Status<>1` that city exclude from reslut set. in this scenarion I want to return cities : 1 , 3.

How I can do this with Sql Query or LINQ query?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should do it.

LINQ:

```
var citiesToExclude = context.Table
    .Where(t => t.Status != 1)
    .Select(t => t.City);
var cities = context.Table
    .Where(t => t.Status == 1)
    .Where(t => !citiesToExclude.Contains(t.City))
    .Select(t => t.City)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

SQL:

```
SELECT City
FROM [Table]
WHERE Status == 1
  AND City NOT IN (SELECT City FROM [Table] WHERE Status <> 1)
GROUP BY City
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Maarten:Can you please write your Lamdba version of your query with linq? I wrote this: `var citiesToExclude = from r in ent.TestAllStatusEqualsOnes
                                  where r.Status != 1
                                  select new { r.City };

            var cities = (from r in ent.TestAllStatusEqualsOnes
                          where r.Status == 1 &&
                                citiesToExclude.Contains(r.City) == false
                          select new { r.City }).Distinct().ToList();` but it didn't work

Comment: What is going wrong? And my version is the lambda version imho.

Comment: @Kerezo `new { r.City }` creates an anonymous object when all you want is an integer.  To fix this, replace `new { r.City }` with `r.City`.  This should make the your query syntax solution work just like Maarten's method syntax solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT   city
FROM     tbl
GROUP BY city
HAVING   COUNT(CASE WHEN status <> 1 THEN 1 END) = 0
```

Comment: can you please write the linq version.

Comment: This does not check if the city has a record with status = 1. This can result in errors if a city has a record with status = 0 and another with status = NULL.

Comment: @Maarten, the OP did not specify whether the status column is allowed to contain `NULL` values. If it's not allowed to, then there is no need to check if `status=1`, otherwise, we would simply add `OR status IS NULL` within the `CASE` expression.

Comment: @Kerezo: Unfortunately, I am unfamiliar with LINQ. However, I believe this to be the most efficient solution provided thus far (avoids using subqueries, subselects, joins, etc.), so perhaps someone who knows LINQ can translate it.

Answer (score 1):

another way

```
select distinct city 
from city C1
 where city=1 and not exists(select * from city C2 where C1.city=C2.city 
 and isnull(Status,0)<>1)
```

Comment: This does not check if the city has a record with status = 1. This can result in errors if a city has a record with status = 0 and another with status = NULL.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tbl.city
FROM 
(SELECT c.city, count(status=1) cnt1, count() cnt2
FROM city c
GROUP BY c.city) AS tbl
WHERE tbl.cnt1=tbl.cnt2 AND tbl.cnt1>0
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just use this? The function doesn't appear to aggregate so `having` is not needed

```
select city 
from [table]
where status = 1
and city not in 
(select city from table where status <> 1)
group by city;
```

unless I am misunderstanding the question?

Comment: missed that part of the Q, Joe.  This will work now though right?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a job for LINQ's [group](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384063.aspx) clause:

```
var cities = from t in table
             group t by t.City into grp
             where grp.Select(g => g.Status).All(s => s == 1)
             select g.Key;
```