# Difference between select r.Field and select new {r.Field}

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0

Link to this two topics:

[Convert Lambda Expression of a query to linq version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11518108/convert-lambda-expression-of-a-query-to-linq-version)

and

[return items that all records related to that items have specific conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11516387/return-items-that-all-records-related-to-that-items-have-specific-conditions)

in first topic @xanatos comment that :

> @Kerezo Be aware that the new { r.City } error appears twice (once in each query). new { r.City } creates an anonymous object with a single property called City that contains the City object (so you are wrapping your City in an object) Without the new you have directly the City

consider this code:

```
var citiesToExclude = from r in ent.TestAllStatusEqualsOnes
                              where r.Status != 1
                              select r.City;

GridView1.DataSource = citiesToExclude;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

if I wrote this code in this way:

```
var citiesToExclude = from r in ent.TestAllStatusEqualsOnes
                              where r.Status != 1
                              select new { r.City };

GridView1.DataSource = citiesToExclude;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

every thing are equal.

I don't understand what is the differencr between `select r.Field` and `select new {r.Field}`. can any one explain more?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anonymous types are *pretty much* the same as any other type. So:

```
select new { r.City }
```

is pretty much identical to:

```
select new SomeType { City = r.City}
```

with:

```
class SomeType { public string City {get;set;} }
```

This then, perhaps makes the distinction simple; it is same as the difference between:

```
string x = obj.City;
```

and

```
SomeType y = new SomeType { City = obj.City };
```

In one case, what you are obtaining *is the city name*. In the other case, you are obtaining an object that *has* a property called `City` which *is* the city name (although it could, in the general case, have other properties too).

The same logic applies inside LINQ.

One handy difference between the two is considering `null`, for example:

```
var city = {some query}.FirstOrDefault();
```

if you are selecting the actual city name, it is a bit hard to tell the difference between "no row" vs "a row, with a null city name". If you are selecting an *object*, you can tell between `obj == null` vs `obj.City == null`.

Answer (score 2):

1 - select r.Field - Returns existing type (E.g. r.Field = string)

2 - select new {r.Field} - Returns new anonymous type object.

Hope it clears the doubt.

Answer (score 2):

The `new { Property = value }` syntax is for creating [Anonymous Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) (reference types with read-only properties and backing support for equality and type re-use).

The difference is your first statement returns `IEnumerable<City Type>` the second statement returns `IEnumerable<anonymous type>`. The anonymous type has a property called `City` of type `City Type`. If property names are not specified as in:

```
new { City = r.City }; // Explicitly-named property called City.
```

The anonymous type takes the name of the property that is used as in:

```
new { r.City }; // Property called City.
```

If the anonymous type cannot resolve the name:

```
new { "a string" };
```

You get a compilation error.

Anonymous types are useful for constructing in-line containers for propagation to another extension method or another part of a linq statement.

Anonymous types cannot be declared as class members and you need to use `var` to get much use out of them. There is IntelliSense support. They also do not satisfy interface definitions and can only contain properties.